# Triggering events on input elements using javascript 

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

I want to trigger an event hen the value of an input element using javascript.The value of the input element is changed using script ,and is not typed.I know that the onChange event fires not after the  value is changed ,but after the value is changed and element looses focus(mouse is clicked outside the element.)..Here the input element does not loose focus.So onChange event  willnot fire.So how to do that..
The following is the script ,once i tried and failed

```
<html>
 <head>
       <script type = 'text/javascript'>
                function changed()
                {
                          alert('changed');
                }
                function change()
                {
                       document.getElementById('myId').value = 'Hello';
                }


       </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type = 'text'  id = 'myId' onChange= 'javascript:changed();'/>
    <input type ='button'  value = 'change'  onClick = 'javascript:change();'/>
 </body>
```

I mean ,the function changed() should be called when the content inside textbox is changed using the function change().How to do that.
Here is the jsfiddle for the code http://jsfiddle.net/BFz2a/

Comment: removed         that 2x javascript :P

Comment: What do you mean by  ", javascript: is obsolete in inline event handlers"?
Also please post this as your answer with some explanation

Comment: If the value of the input element is changed using script, that's when you can trigger the event...

Answer (score 2):

Call `changed()` after `change()`: http://jsfiddle.net/BFz2a/11/

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById('myId').value = 'Hello';
    changed(); // Calls the other function
}
```

Contents inside event listeners (`onchange=" this is inside "`) is parsed as JavaScript. So, `javascript:` is **obsolete**. In fact, it is treated as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).
The `javascript:...` prefix is only meaningful in links, eg `<a href="javascript:alert('test');">Test</a>`.

Comment: it is not working ...I need to get the alert message when the content inside the text is changed using the button ..

Comment: @JinuJD See the line on top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple

```
function change(){
   var el = document.getElementById('myId');
   el.value = 'Hello';
   el.onchange(); // or simply call changed();
}
```

and `javascript:` is not needed inside `onclick` and `onchange` simply use

`onClick = "change();"`

Answer (score 1):

In your function that handles the click event you could manually call the onchange event for the Input.

```
function change()
{
    var inputEl = document.getElementById("myId");
    inputEl.value = 'Hello';
    inputEl.onchange();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function change(){
    var el=document.getElementById('myId');
    el.value="Something";
    changed(el);
}
function changed(el){
    alert(el.value);
}
change();
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpanw/3/).